# How can I change the global tint color programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard, tint

My project needs to switch between 2 different global tint values. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the tint color of the `UIWindow` of the application. You can either use the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` but better is to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window`.

Comment: this is the code I have wrote:     UIWindow* mWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    mWindow.tintColor = [UIColor themeColorNamed:@"themeColour"];  CEAFDC also suggested a good answer. Which is most correct?

Comment: You say you need to change the tint in runtime, in which case this is a better solution.

Answer (score 8):

`UIAppearance` is the answer! It sets property to all the objects of that class (and subclasses).

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:(UIColor *)]
```

You can change the `backgroudColor` of all the buttons too

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)]
```

Comment: hrmm I was about to do this:     UIWindow* mWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    mWindow.tintColor = [UIColor themeColorNamed:@"themeColour"];  Is this incorrect? Should I just do UIView appearance instead? It is the global value I need to change... but I guess everything is a view?

Comment: UIAppearance is recommended, it will change the tint color of all subclasses too. Like buttons, toolbars...

Comment: @CEAFDC: Any `UIView` descendant will inherit the superview's `tintColor` if it isn't explicitly set.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Booth methos will have the same result. But this applies just to tint color, UIAppearance is more general

Comment: This method will not change existing controls' tint color after they have been created. If @jimbob needs to change the tint color in runtime, setting the window's tint color is a better option.

Comment: `UIView`'s `tintColor` does not have `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`. See `UIView.h`.

Comment: Ok, now I'm convinced. Thanks :)
UIWindow tintColor is the way to go

Comment: There's also an overrideable tintColorDidChange on UIView, described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/tintColorDidChange